# Openlayers - Why different distances results

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to understand what is wrong with this.

I have pair of coordinates and I calculate the distance between them. Now, with that distance I draw a circle in each coordinates and give it the radius of the distance calculated, but the circle is always smaller.

```
var p1 = [lat01, lng01]
var p2 = [lat02, lng02]

var distance = p1.distanceTo(p2)

mycircle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(p1.lng01, p1.lat01),
        distance,
        40,
        0
    )
```

Now the problem is that the drawn circle is always smaller, and it looks that the bigger the distance, the bigger the error.

So, the edge of the circle should be on top of the other coordinate, but is always smaller.

Is this a bug in openlayers or I'm missing something.

Comment: What unit does the `distanceTo` function return? In the docs, it says that `createRegularPolygon` uses "map units", but it doesn't specify for `distanceTo`.

Comment: distanceTo returns distance in meters. But now I change my code and don´t use the distanceTo no more, I use:
`var p1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng01, lat01);
var p2 = new openLayers.LonLat(lng01,lat01);
var distance = OpenLayers.Util.distVincenty (p1,p2);`
The distVicenty is more accurate, but this don´t solve the problem of the size of the circle, it is always smaller.
I think that is because the circle radius is in a straight line and not Geodesic.
But I still like to know how to solve this.

Comment: Are you doing this over some special basemap like bing or google? If so the problem would be projections.

Answer (score 0):

I use to face similar issue, which is caused by projection, do you transform your p1, p2 to map projection already? see [transform section](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.transform)